# Deeply nested data objects in multidimensional object

Tags: object, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a multidimensional object and using Vue, I am trying to make the inner object reactive.

My object looks like this:

```
data() {
   return {
       myObject: {}
   }
}
```

And the filled data looks like this:

```
myObject: {
   1: {         // (client)
     0: "X",    // (index) : (value)
     1: "Y"
   },
   2: {
     0: "A",
     2: "B"
   }
}
```

If I try using:

```
let value = "X";
let client = 1;
let index = 1;

let obj = {};
obj[client][index] = value;
this.myObject = Object.assign({}, this.myObject, obj);
```

It throws an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

And if I try below, it overwrites the initial values as it is initially setting the object to `{}`

```
let obj = {};
obj[index] = value;
let parentObj = {};
parentObj[client] = obj;
this.myObject = Object.assign({}, this.myObject, parentObj);
```

What is the proper way of adding the values to the multidimensional object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, `dim2Thing[1][1] = ...` expressions require `dim2Thing[1]` to exist. This is why you get the error you mentioned. So you can do two expressions, which should work fine:

`dim2Thing[1] = dim2Thing[1] || {}`
`dim2Thing[1][1] = otherThing`

For the last block, you mention that it "overwrites the initial values"

I think what's actually happening here is just that `Object.assign` is not recursive. It only merges top-level keys. So if `parentObj` has a key that over-laps with `this.myObj`, then sub-keys will be lost.

```
Object.assign({ a: { b: 2} }, { a: { c: 3 } }) // returns { a: { c: 3 }  }
```

This is what I interpret your code as trying to do - though I am unfamiliar with vue.js at this time, so I cannot assure it will have the desired result to your webpage:

```
let value = "X";
let client = 1;
let index = 1;

const newObj = Object.assign({}, this.myObject);
// if you have lodash _.set is handy
newObj[client] = newObj[client] || {}; // whatever was there, or a new object
newObj[client][index] = value
this.myObject = newObj
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me the perspective of `|| {}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array, thats reactive by design.
If you need to get elements from the array in your template or anywhere just add a find method

// temp

```
late
<div v-for="(value, idx) in myArray">{{find(obj => obj.id === idx)}}</div>

methods: {
  find (searchFunction) {
    return this.myArray.find(searchFunction)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Due to the design of my structure, I can't use arrays but otherwise `.find` would work like charm